# Problem in cloudUpload control while file size more than 4 MB

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, cloud

I am working on radcloudupload control to upload files in amazon s3 server using c#. I am facing problem when I am going to upload a file more than 4 mb. it is saying file size related issue, but I have followed all the steps to upload a file more than 4 mb. code is as below:

```
<telerik:RadCloudUpload ID="RadCloudUpload1" runat="server" MaxFileSize="1048576" RenderMode="Lightweight"
                 MultipleFileSelection="Automatic"  OnFileUploaded="RadCloudUpload1_FileUploaded" ProviderType="Amazon"  >
        </telerik:RadCloudUpload>
```

also I have placed the below mentioned points to web.config for large file upload.

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" executionTimeout="3600" />
</system.web>

<system.webServer>   
    <security>
      <authorization>      
      </authorization>
<requestFiltering>
<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1048576000" />
</requestFiltering>
    </security>
<system.webServer>
```

how to resolve?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know specifically for your control, or Amazon, but generally, for ASP.NET, you control upload size through the http setting, so yours is too small

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" executionTimeout="3600" />
```

Try setting the `maxRequestLength` to 4 MB (or more): 4194304.

Comment: Thank you for replying, tried with `<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="4194304" executionTimeout="3600" />`  but not working same error.

Comment: Try removing executionTimeout. I'm not sure it will help though.

Comment: Solved !!!    https://forums.asp.net/p/2170768/6318665.aspx?p=True&t=637359944604382034

Comment: Great! Add the answer here too.

Comment: solved by this `<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="41943040" executionTimeout="3600" />` and thank you too!!